# Liferay 7.4 theme development with bootstrap/clay css variables in browser

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme

In previous liferay versions, when developing a custom theme, i used to lookup all the involved `var(--XYZ)` css variables and overwrote them in `_clay_variables.scss` (e.g. $btn-border-radius and so on).

With liferay 7.4 this is still valid and working, but I don't see the css var(--) in the browser inspector to know what could be modified and overwritten.

It seems like these variables are getting removed when building the css for the deployment. Is there a configuration to develop a custom theme (locally) and still see the possible variables on inspecting?

Using the `classic-theme` this still works - the served css file is full of var(--) variables.